# Is there a way to execute a chain of work items periodically in android WorkManager

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I am developing an application and have based my content fetch on WorkManager. I have a chain of work items that i want to execute periodically. My concern is that as per documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/recurring-work)

I can not use a periodic work inside a chain of work items , but can I execute a chain of work items periodically ?

I have explored multiple posts but have not found the exact answer.

Comment: What if you make your *chain of work* inside your **periodic work** request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PeriodicWorkRequest` can in turn `enqueue` a chain of `OneTimeWorkRequest`s. That's probably the best way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: The challenge in that is , i am not able to observe when the chain will finish, since the PeriodicWorkItem finished as soon as it queues up the Chain of work items, which might finish at a later point in time.

Comment: You can always tag the chain of work separately. That way you can just use getWorkInfosByTagLiveDat().